# Override Laravel Routes with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4

Hey guys I've developed a school database grouped by city and state but I put cities word before routes.

so now every url comes like x.com/cities/city_name/state_name/school_name

my routes are like

```
Route::get('cities/{cityName}')
```

But now I want to delete this cities word because of SEO. When I remove cities word from my routes.php  my other pages are don't work (admin, about_us)

so I thought maybe I can hide cities word with htaccess is it possible ? if so how can i do it ?

Comment: You should change it in the source/code base before it gets live and keep it simple. Change the other pages to fit with new route and this time use named route to generate `link`.

Comment: there are tons of view files that I don't wanna change :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't be an answer you like, but take it more as a warning for future projects: use **named routes**.

If you had your route, say:

```
Route::get('cities/{cityName}', array('as' => 'city', 'uses' => 'CityController@city'));
```

And you had created your routes in the views using any of the provided methods:

```
route('city', array('cityName' => 'New York'));
form_open(array('route' => array('city', 'New York'));
URL::route('city', array('cityName' => 'New York'));
```

Now you wouldn't need to change anything in your views, you could just change the route itself:

```
Route::get('cities', array('as' => 'city', 'uses' => 'CityController@city'));
```

And forget about the rest (even the now missing parameter. I know, it won't look perfect...)

If you still want to go the .htaccess route you could try:

```
^cities/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /cities/$2/$3 [L]
```